# Error when trying to 'mvn clean install' Gerrit's replication plugin

Tags: maven, replication, gerrit

This is probably a newbie question, but I'm new to Maven.

I'm trying to build Gerrit's replication plugin, ["since the master branch (and thus Gerrit 2.5) no longer supports replication out of the box."](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/repo-discuss/n6u1xEjFGxU)

So I did clone https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/replication and executed `mvn clean install` inside the new directory. The error message is:

```bsh
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building replication 1.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for com.google.gerrit:gerrit-plugin-api:jar:2.6-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.840s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Apr 25 17:30:10 BRT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/105M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project replication: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication:replication:jar:1.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.google.gerrit:gerrit-plugin-api:jar:2.6-SNAPSHOT in https://gerrit-api.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/release/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be
reattempted until the update interval of gerrit-api-repository has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

It looks like this URL isn't valid: https://gerrit-api.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/release/ -- but like I said, I'm new to Maven so I'm not sure how to proceed. I did some research, but I don't know what I'm looking for.

Any pointer would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things -

1. You are missing the gerrit-plugin-api.jar.  This currently isn't provided upstream, so you must build it yourself.  I believe running `mvn install` from a Gerrit repository will package and add this jar to your system.
2. You don't want to run `install`, you just want to run `package` on the plugin.  `mvn package` will put the .jar in the target/ folder, which you then copy to your plugins folder inside your Gerrit installation.

Good luck!

Comment: Brad, I'll try this in a couple of hours and then get back to you. Thanks a lot for answering. :)

Comment: I'm accepting your answer, since it seems the way to go. Unfortunately, Gerrit repos seem to be facing issues lately (details are below). Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Like Brad mentioned, I am missing the **gerrit-plugin-api.jar**. Unfortunately, I was not able to build it, since the Gerrit repos seem to be facing issues lately, as mentioned in other threads ([this one, for instance](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/repo-discuss/UvM4IvF7n9A) - from two days ago).

Anyway, below are my additional steps based on Brad's answer (hopefully this may help others):

```bsh
git clone https://gerrit.googlesource.com/gerrit
cd gerrit/gerrit-plugin-api/
mvn clean install

[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Gerrit Code Review - Plugin API 2.7-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for com.google.gerrit:gerrit-sshd:jar:2.7-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for com.google.gerrit:gerrit-httpd:jar:2.7-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for com.google.gerrit:gerrit-pgm:jar:2.7-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.342s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Apr 26 10:52:54 BRT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/105M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project gerrit-plugin-api: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.google.gerrit:gerrit-plugin-api:jar:2.7-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.google.gerrit:gerrit-sshd:jar:2.7-SNAPSHOT, com.google.gerrit:gerrit-httpd:jar:2.7-SNAPSHOT, com.google.gerrit:gerrit-pgm:jar:2.7-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.google.gerrit:gerrit-sshd:jar:2.7-SNAPSHOT in https://gerrit-maven.commondatastorage.googleapis.com was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of gerrit-maven has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

---

```
EDIT
```

These are the steps that worked for me, in case someone else faces the same issue.

```
git clone https://gerrit.googlesource.com/gerrit
```

Check available 'versions'

```
git branch -r 
git checkout -b 2.5 origin/stable-2.5
```

The steps didn't work on the master branch in my environment, and I'm using 2.5...

So yeah, 2.5.

```
cd gerrit
mvn clean install
```

This will rebuild the entire universe, go grab a cup of coffee. :)

.. when done

```
cd gerrit-plugin-api/
mvn package
```

This also takes some time...

If everything goes fine, you can copy the jar at the target folder, like:

```
cp target/<large-name>.jar ~/replication.jar
```

Finally install it (from ~):

```
ssh -p 29418 localhost gerrit plugin install -n name \ - <replication.jar
```

Details on how to install Gerrit plugins are [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/cmd-plugin-install.html).

The thing is, now I'm getting another error, something like:

> "A binding to (something) was already configured at (something)."

But that's another story / thread / post...

Thanks and good luck!

Comment: You are trying to build just the plugin-api.jar, but it has dependencies on other gerrit packages (com.google.gerrit:gerrit-sshd:jar:2.7-SNAPSHOT, etc).  Go up a directory to the root gerrit folder and run `mvn install`

Comment: I tried that and I got the same error. It looks like it may work with branch 2.6 tho (I'm on the master branch), according to this thread: http://bit.ly/11K3pSI. I'm trying it now. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Do a `mvn -P all clean install` on the toplevel, not inside `gerrit-plugin-api`.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to fix is is to change the pom.xml and use a version that is not a snapshot. I was trying to build the delete-project for the stable-2.6 branch and was facing the same issue. All that needs to be done is to change the Gerrit-ApiVersion:

```
     <Gerrit-ApiType>plugin</Gerrit-ApiType>
-    <Gerrit-ApiVersion>2.6-SNAPSHOT</Gerrit-ApiVersion>
+    <Gerrit-ApiVersion>2.6-rc2</Gerrit-ApiVersion>
   </properties>
   <name>Delete Project Gerrit Plugin</name>
```

Comment: This highlights another problem installing these plugins - although the main gerrit repo is following a fairly common "branch-by-rule and tag releases" strategy, the plugins I have been dealing with are not branching or tagging at all.  This means you have to hunt back through the commit history of the plugin's pom.xml with the Gerrit-ApiVersion property at the next snapshot version following the  stable Gerrit release you're using.  E.g. for Gerrit 2.7, I have to check out the first commit in delete-project where Gerrit-ApiVersion was bumped to 2.8-SNAPSHOT.

Answer (score 0):

Building off of @Conaaando's answer, I performed these exact steps and successfully am using the plugin. Steps courtesy of http://asheepapart.blogspot.com/2013/12/how-to-build-gerrit-replication-plugin.html

```
git clone --recursive https://gerrit.googlesource.com/gerrit
```

You need the **--recursive** here because the plugins are actually git submodules and won't otherwise be cloned along with your repo.

If you've already cloned, you can run `git submodule init; git submodule update`

```
cd gerrit
git checkout -b stable-2.7 origin/stable-2.7
mvn install -DskipTests=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true
```

It's not necessary to skip the tests or generating Java Doc, but it will greatly improve your compile time and decrease the amount of memory maven uses

```
cd gerrit-plugin-api
mvn package -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true
```

This creates the jar that will be necessary for the replication plugin to get built

```
cd plugins/replication
mvn package -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true
```

At this point, you have compiled and packaged the replication jar! All you need to do now is register it with your Gerrit server. For simplicity, I'll pretend your gerrit server is running at `gerrit.example.com`. These steps copy the replication jar to your review server and then instruct the review server to install the plugin from that copied location.

```
scp target/replication-2.7.jar gerrit.example.com:/tmp/
ssh -p 29418 gerrit.example.com gerrit plugin install -n replication /tmp/replication-2.7.jar
```